# Making a foreach of img's with a flex display thats also responsive

Tags: php, laravel-blade, tailwind-css

I need to make a photo layout with an array of images. But what I want to do is make 2 small img's and 1 big one next to each other. One time the big one needs to be left and on the next "Row" I want it placed on the right side. ( see Sketch )

The problem is that I have no clue where to start. I got this so far but have no idea how to format this in a foreach with only images.

```
<div class="w-full flex flex-wrap -mx-2">
    <div class="small-images w-1/3 px-2 ">
        <div class="bg-gray-200 ">r</div>
        <div class="bg-gray-200 mt-4">r</div>
    </div>
    <div class="large w-2/3 px-2 bg-gray-200">r</div>
</div>

<div class="w-full flex mt-4 flex-wrap -mx-2">
    <div class="large w-2/3 px-2 bg-gray-200">r</div>
    <div class="small-images w-1/3 px-2 ">
        <div class="bg-gray-200 ">r</div>
        <div class="bg-gray-200 mt-4">r</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using **Tailwindcss** and tried to do it with grids but sadly we also need to support IE 11 so grids are out of the picture with the lack of support.

I was wondering if this is possible with Flex boxes?

I'm using a **Laravel** project with blade and **tailwindcss**. Any suggestions or tips would be helpful thank you and if something is unclear let me know so i can try to explain it better :)

[image: layout]

Comment: Use bootstrap 3 grid (floats) to solve your issue.

Comment: How does it work with a foreach though ? i cant make it like the sketch with it right ? or am i not seeing something you do at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#customizing-the-grid

Comment: Also I preffur not to use bootstrap since it will break some of the tailwind classes like container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved my issue with changing the format I got in the array.

I changed it to groups with 3 images. So if I had 10 images, I would have 4 groups where 3 groups have 3 img's in it. And the last group with 1 left over image.

Then the only thing I had to do is a foreach and check on the key of the group. 
If it was an even number I showed the Left format and oneven I showed the right format.

Dont know if it will help anyone else, but might as well post my solution :)
There is probably a better solution for it but this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who will look for this in future - **use grid instead of flexboxes for similar task**.

**Using flex instead of grid**

Let's start with the fact that you do not need to make separate code for left sided and right sided elements. Flex has [flex-direction](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-direction.asp) option, so you can just reverse order in loop. In Tailwind it is `flex-row-reverse` class ([docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex-direction)).

In Laravel Blade foreach (or any other PHP foreach) you need to just chunk results by 3 elements. Just convert eloquent results to array and use php's build in function [array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php).

```
@foreach (array_chunk($collection->toArray(), 3) as $chunk)
    <div class="w-full flex flex-wrap -mx-2 mb-2 @if($loop->even) flex-row-reverse @endif">
        <div class="small-images w-1/3 px-2 ">
            <div class="bg-gray-200 ">{{ array_get($chunk, '0.title') }}</div>
            <div class="bg-gray-200 mt-4">{{ array_get($chunk, '1.title') }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="large w-2/3 px-2 bg-gray-200">{{ array_get($chunk, '2.title') }}</div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

On Laravel 7 you will have to use Arr::get instead of array_get or install helpers.

You did not provided any PHP code so I do not know how you store images in model. In my example I will use text, but for images you need to simply put img there the way you need them.

If you need to use model methods inside loop (for ex. if you have `$model->getThumbnail('medium')`) then you cannot convert all results to array like I did. Instead use collection method [chunk(3)](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-chunk) and inside loop get correct item by using [slice(0, 1)](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-slice).